# Are Immutable ECMAScript Modules Speced Behavior?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

Javascript, somewhat infamously, allows your entire program to modify any object.  In Node.js this means you can modify a CommonJS module at runtime.  If you have a program like this

```
// File: change-it.js
const express = require('express')
express.myProp = 'hello world'

// File: index.js
require('./change-it')
const express = require('express')
console.log(express.myProp)
```

and run it, you'll get the following output.

```
% node index.js
hello world
```

That is, we've successfully added a property to the *express* module.

However, the new native ECMAScript modules (also know as ESM modules -- the ones that use `import`) do not apear to support this behavior.  In fact, Node.js outright rejects it.

That is, a program like this

```
// File: index.mjs
import * as a from './a.mjs'
import * as b from './b.mjs'
console.log(a)
console.log(b)

// File: a.mjs
import * as b from './a.mjs'
b.myProp = 'hijacked!'
export const a = 'hello world'

// File: b.mjs
export const b = 'goodbye world'
```

Will error out with the following error

```
% node index.mjs
file:///path/to/a.mjs:2
b.myProp = 'hijacked!'
         ^

TypeError: Cannot add property myProp, object is not extensible
    at file:///path/to/a.mjs:2:10
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:198:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:385:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:88:5)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:61:12)
```

My Question: Is this speced behavior of ECMAScript modules, or is this a choice the Node.js developers made?  If speced is there a section (or sections?) of [the ECMAScript](https://tc39.es/ecma262) that covers expectations here?

(I've tried looking at [the ECMAScript spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/) and I'm afraid I don't speak whatever dialect of engineering english the smart folks who put that together do)

Comment: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-module-namespace-exotic-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, module namespaces - for example, the `a` after the line:

```
import * as a from './a.mjs'
```

cannot be mutated. Its [IsExtensible](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-module-namespace-exotic-objects-isextensible) property is:

> The [[IsExtensible]] internal method of a module namespace exotic object takes no arguments and returns a normal completion containing false. It performs the following steps when called:
>
> 1. Return false.

Only extensible objects can have properties added to them.

Comment: or the TL;DR is ... *yes, it is speced behaviour* :p